# How to model interval scale

Tags: xml, xsd, intervals

I want to collect speed-data and aggregate them in buckets (intervals [0, 10], [11, 20], [21, 30], and so on).

I have trouble defining a matching XML structure that fullfills these requirements:

- for each interval the unit (km/h, m/s) and duration (seconds) and underlying datatype (int) should be known
- for each interval the upper and lower bound should be documented (?`minInclusive`, `maxInclusive`)
- an interval occurence can be NULL (optional)
- the xml should be easy so that processing is fast

Givven three type of speeds (for example horizontal acceleration, vertical deceleration and centrifugal force) should have its own [`dataType`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#datatype) and shall be measured in interval scales [`value space`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#value-space) 
So measure the number of seconds in each speed bucket for the different speedTypes:

- bucket_0 from 0 km/h to 10 km/h,
- bucket_1 from 11 km/h to 20 km/h
- bucket_2 from 21 km/h to 30 km/h

I would like to make the types and scales (buckets) self explanatory / self documenting.

The current idea is to do this

```
...
<xs:horizontalAcceleration>
  <xs:scale0>0</xs:scale0>
  <xs:scale1>0</xs:scale1>
  <xs:scale2>0</xs:scale2>      
  ...
  <xs:scale19>0</xs:scale19>
  <xs:scale20>0</xs:scale20>
</xs:horizontalAcceleration>

<xs:verticalAcceleration>
  <xs:scale0>0</xs:scale0>
  ...
  <xs:scale20>0</xs:scale20>
</xs:verticalAcceleration>
...
```

The ranges for each speedType can be the same or they can overlap.

### My questions are

- how to encode / notate in which range / scale a certain value lies?
- How to include information to improve documentation?
- for different speed types
- for different units (km/h / minute or miles per hour per minute) of measure
- should i use an list or enumeration
- are there difference regarding speed of processing of the xml

### Update

To my understanding the constraining facets `minInclusive` and `maxInclusive` could be used to mark the lower and upper bound of each interval / each scale. To quote `Datatypes derived by restriction from duration may also specify values for the following ·constraining facets·:`

Do i have to define a speedRange for every interval / scale like this

```
<xs:simpleType name="speedRange_0">
 <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
  <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
  <xs:maxInclusive value="10"/>
 </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="speedRange_1">
 <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
  <xs:minInclusive value="11"/>
  <xs:maxInclusive value="21"/>
 </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

### Links

- [w3.org duration](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#duration)
- [IntervalTypes](http://www.ddialliance.org/Specification/DDI-Lifecycle/3.2/XMLSchema/FieldLevelDocumentation/schemas/logicalproduct_xsd/complexTypes/IntervalType.html)

Comment: Date ranges in XML use the ISO 8601 standard.  https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/  Search this page for "duration".  I'm not sure this is what you're looking for but it may help.

Comment: I am not sure if understand the duration part or if it would fit -  i will update my question above